# Fetching a random record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

i am developing a ruby on rails question bank application.i want to know how to retrive a random records from database with out any duplication.and i am using a MYSQL as a database.Also all the random records show in the view.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution: 1**

> User.limit(10).order("RAND()")

**Solution: 2**

> ids = User.pluck(:id).shuffle[0..9] 
>   
>  
>   User.where(id: ids)

Comment: pluck is not working with ruby 1.9.2

Comment: For ruby 1.9.2 try this, ids = User.select(:id).collect(&:id).shuffle[0..9]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my last, i write that almost thoughtlessly.

registers = YourModel.order("RANDOM()").limit(number_of_records)

Comment: thank u.but sort_by is not working for me....

Comment: I've edited my last post. Try that @user2903300!